# Merge a set of strings based on overlaps

Tags: algorithms, graphs, strings

I have a set of strings that are slices of a single, longer string. It is not guaranteed, however, that any two strings from this set must overlap: only that all of them together overlap. I want to reconstruct the original longer string.

For example, suppose the longer string is LGHFDJGHSJGHDFKSJBSFSHJKADGHS. The slices might be FKSJBSFS, JKADGHS, LGHFDJGHS, SFSHJKA and GHSJGHDFK. I need an algorithm to reconstruct the original LGHFDJGHSJGHDFKSJBSFSHJKADGHS.

I understand that this algorithm may be somewhat probabilistic: given any two strings, the probability that they overlap by pure chance is $\frac{2}{n}$ where $n$ is the size of the alphabet used. I want to find the "best" overlapping longer string.

So far I've asked around and I've been told to look into suffix trees and de Bruijn graphs. I have done so but I can't see how I can apply them to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [DNA sequence assembly problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_assembly), an algorithms problem that has been well studied in the literature.  You can apparently find [entire courses](https://www.coursera.org/learn/dna-sequencing) on the subject.  In general, [the problem is NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem).  However, there are many algorithms that seem to work well in practice; [greedy assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_assembly#Greedy_algorithm) is one very simple approach, but there are [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_novo_sequence_assemblers).

Comment: Hmm, does this mean that it would be suboptimal for me to write my own implementation of the algorithm?

Comment: @Bluefire, given that it is a complex subject that has received a lot of study, most likely!  But suboptimal might well be good enough in your particular situation; or it might not.  In general if you have enough redundancy in your short strings, almost any algorithm is fine; it's when you have less redundancy that the algorithm becomes more critical.

Comment: That makes sense. I can assume that my inputs won't be that lengthy and there will be a fair amount of redundancy, so I guess there is no need for over-optimisation and a greedy algorithm will do.